# Adding delimited text layer with Python outside of QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm trying to create a QGIS project using Jupyter environment.
Until now I managed to add a Raster layer.

I now want to add a csv file, in QGIS I would add it like that: Layer -> Add Layer -> Add delimited Text Layer.

How can I do the same using Python?

This is what I have now:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject,QgsRasterLayer,QgsRaster,QgsVectorLayer
import boto3
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,QMessageBox,QDialog

project = QgsProject.instance()
#here I add the raster layer
fileInfo = QFileInfo('rasterlayer')
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer('rasterlayer', basename)
if not rlayer.isValid():
   print("Layer failed to load!")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

This is what I tried to use to add the delimited text layer and I keep geeing Invalid error.

```
uri='file:///coordinatestry.csv?delimiter=,&yField=y&xField=x'
layer = QgsRasterLayer(uri, 'name', 'delimitedtext')

uri = ("file:///{}?"
               "&delimiter={}"
               "&xField={}"
               "&yField={}"
               "&crs={}"
               "&decimal").format('coordinatestry.csv',
                                        ",",
                                        "x",
                                        "y",
                                        "EPSG:4326",",")
vlayer = QgsRasterLayer(uri, "layer", "delimitedtext")

fileName = 'coordinatestry.csv' # the path to the csv
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
uri = "file:/"+fileName+"?delimiter=%s" % (",") # tried without the file:/ too and different delimiters  
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, baseName, "delimitedtext")
```

I keep getting this: `<QgsRasterLayer: 'layer' (Invalid)>`

The end goal is to use Atlas export as images for the coordinates in the csv on the raster layer.

Any ideas how to make the adding delimited text layer work?

Edit: Tried this as well as was suggested in comments:

```
uri = "file://{}/coordinatestry.csv?delimiter={}&xField={}&yField={}".format(os.getcwd(), ",", "inside_x", "inside_y")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "layer name you like", "delimitedtext")
```

Still got : <QgsVectorLayer: 'layer name you like' (Invalid)>

Comment: Just have a look at the PyQGIS Cookbook, you're not defining properly the parameters to load your raster: the https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers

Comment: I tried it again now: uri = "file://{}/coordinatestry.csv?delimiter={}&xField={}&yField={}".format(os.getcwd(), ",", "inside_x", "inside_y")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "layer name you like", "delimitedtext")
Got this: <QgsVectorLayer: 'layer name you like' (Invalid)>

Comment: What is your OS? I'm able to run the two last lines without issue e.g a valid layer. It seems to be a path issue IMHO

Comment: I'm using AWS EC2 Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, with anaconda environment (Working from a Jupyter notebook). I tried to play around with the path, as the file is in the same folder as the notebook but it didn't work.